# android view hierarchy with resource id

Tags: android, view, hierarchy

is there a way to get the hierarchy of the current layout of the device along with the resource id of the elements in the hierarchy?

I found a way to get the hierarchy but the IDs of the elements weren't there.

Also, note that i'm not doing that from inside the application with the current layout.

Comment: help me to understand. You have a view hierarchy. A LinearLayout with a number of children, for instance. And you want to collect the id of every child of this LinearLayout?

Comment: The question was edited, please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

View has method: getParent() and getId(). ViewGroup hasMethod: getChildren(). It is enough to get full hierarchy.
If you want to find out View hierarchy of elements in layout you should inflate this layout using LayoutInflater.

Another solution is to create your own xml parser.

Comment: I don't have access to these things .. my code is running out of the application responsible for the current layout, but yet, it's running on the device.

Comment: Is it for testing purposes? You can check robotium_solo project https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started. It scans all view hierachy.